# How to show divs like stairs in css?

Tags: html, css

How can I Make a design like below, consider dashes are boxes

```
-----------                              -----------
-----------                              -----------
   -----------                        ------------
   -----------                        ------------
      -----------                 ------------
      -----------                 ------------
         ----------------------------------
         ----------------------------------
```

Comment: Which part exactly is a stair? Like is every single dash one box = one div?

Comment: Have you tried anything? Like are the widths dynamically changing depending on the screen width?

Comment: What exactly is the problem you're having?  Seems fairly straightforward with either `margin`, `padding` or `position` or use a table or bootstrap "table" - another option would be to use css transform rotation - depending on how you want to solve it.

Comment: I think you are expecting a dynamic code where the number of elements and stairs can vary So I wrote an answer here accordingly as your question is marked jQuery as well

Answer (score 0):

Here is the answer!

```css
.clear{
  clear:both;height:0px;line-height:0px;overflow:hidden
  }
.container{width:100%}
.row{width:100%;margin-bottom:5px}
.div{
  width:100px;
  height:5px;
  background:blue;
  
}
.container div:nth-child(2n){float:right}
.container div:nth-child(2n-1){float:left}

.div3{float:left;margin-left:10%}
.div4{float:right;margin-right:10%}
.div5{float:left;margin-left:15%}
.div6{float:right;margin-right:15%}
.div7{float:left;margin-left:20%}
.div8{float:right;margin-right:20%}
.div9{float:left;margin-left:25%}
.div10{float:right;margin-right:25%}
.div11{width:100%;margin:5px 0}
.div12{width:100%;margin:5px 0}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="div1 div"></div><div class="div2 div"></div>
    <div class=clear></div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="row">
    <div class="div3 div"></div><div class="div4 div"></div>
    <div class=clear></div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="row">
    <div class="div5 div"></div><div class="div6 div"></div>
    <div class=clear></div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="row">
    <div class="div7 div"></div><div class="div8 div"></div>
    <div class=clear></div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="row">
    <div class="div9 div"></div><div class="div10 div"></div>
    <div class=clear></div>
  </div>
  <div class="row">
    <div class="div11 div"></div><div class="div12 div"></div>
    <div class=clear></div>
  </div>
  
  
</div>
```

Comment: Thank u for your help :-)

Answer (score 0):

You could utilize flexbox:

```
<div class="stairs">
  <div class="set">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="set">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
  <div class="set">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
   <div class="set">
    <div class="box"></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS (SCSS used in Codepen)

```
.stairs {
  background: #333;
  max-width: 600px;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.set {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
.set .box:nth-child(2) {
  margin-left: auto;
}

.set:nth-child(2) {
  max-width: 90%;
}

.set:nth-child(3) {
  max-width: 80%;
}

.set:nth-child(4) {
  max-width: 70%;
}
.set:nth-child(4) .box {
  width: 100%;
}

.box {
  width: 100px;
  background: white;
  padding: 1rem;
}
```

https://codepen.io/anon/pen/pwWbda

Comment: Thank u for your help :-)

Comment: No problem. Edited using max-width so it's more flexible to different screen sizes

Answer (score 0):

The question is marked jQuery and all are answering CSS only.I had to spend a few hours in producing your problem but I think this is the answer you were expecting Here is  the code and the JSFiddle  I made:

```js
$('document').ready(function() {
 function makeEqual(blocks,dash) {
  var n =blocks;
  var widthSize = dash *10;
  var i=0;
  var equal = "";
  var contentName = "";
for(i=0;i<n;i++) {
 
  if(i==(n-1)) {
   contentName='contentL'+i;
  equal = "<div id="+contentName+">"+produceDashStructure(dash*3)+"</div>"; 
  $("#main").append(equal);
  $("#"+contentName).css({marginLeft:i*widthSize , width:widthSize*3});
   for(j=i;j>0;j--) {
     contentName='contentR'+j;
      equal = "<div id="+contentName+">"+produceDashStructure(dash)+"</div>"; 
      $("#main").append(equal);
      $("#"+contentName).css({marginLeft:((n-j)+i+2)*widthSize , width:widthSize , bottom: (((n-j)*2))*55 , position: "relative" });
    }
  }
   else {
    contentName='contentL'+i;
      equal = "<div id="+contentName+">"+produceDashStructure(dash)+"</div>"; 
      $("#main").append(equal);
  $("#"+contentName).css({marginLeft:i*widthSize , width:widthSize});
    }
  }
  
  }
  function produceDashStructure(dash) {    
      var dashedStructure = "";
    for(var i=0;i<dash;i++) {
         dashedStructure += "- "; 
      }
       return dashedStructure+"<br/><br/>"+dashedStructure;
  }

  makeEqual(5,5); 
  /*makeEqual(Number of Blocks you want , Number of - you want in a block) */
})
```

```css
#main {
  top: 10px;
  left: 10px;
  width: 30 px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="main">
    
</div>
```

[JSfiddle of mine](https://jsfiddle.net/Ishan_Mahajan/2qqusL45/11/)

**Update:Updated code to all dynamic dashs in a block and elements in it.**